# How do I validate a string to make sure there is no non-digits and integers less than or equal to 1?

Tags: c++, loops, validation, exception, getline

So I am currently working on a program in c++. I have written the following function. The line where it says "//code here" is where my issue is. Basically the program allows the user to create their own quiz txt file. For the question "How many questions should the quiz have?" the user will enter a number that represents the amount of questions. The issue arises when the user input will have to be validated.

**Can anyone help me create a loop that does the following?**

1. makes sure the user enters only numbers.
2. makes sure the numbers entered are greater than 1.
3. gives the user an error message if they entered a non digit.
4. gives the user an error message if they entered a number less than 2.
5. the program validates if the user just presses the enter key.

Once that is all sorted out the program will set NumberOfQuestions equal to the user input after converting it to an int.

```
void WriteOutQuestions(string &QuizName)
{
ofstream WriteOut;
string filename = "";
string userInput = "";
int numberOfQuestions;
char userInputChar = '0';
bool IncludeCommments = false;

cout << "Name your file\n";
getline(cin, filename);
cout << "Now give your new quiz a title\n";
getline(cin, QuizName);
cout << "How many questions should the quiz have?\n";
getline(cin, userInput);

//code here

numberOfQuestions = stoi(userInput);
cout << "The quiz will contain " << numberOfQuestions << " questions." << endl;
cout<< "Would you like to include comments in any of the choices?\n";
cout << "[Y/y for yes N/n for No]\n";
getline(cin, userInput);

if (userInput == "y" && userInput == "Y")
    IncludeCommments = true;
else
    cout << "Comments disabled by user...\n";

WriteOut.open(filename + ".txt");
if (!WriteOut)
{
    cout << "The file was not found...\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "File was read!\n";
}
WriteOut << QuizName << endl;
WriteOut << numberOfQuestions << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; ++i)
{
    cout << "What is question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);
    WriteOut << "Q" << i + 1 << " " + userInput << endl;
    
    cout << "What is choice A for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);
    WriteOut << "A) " + userInput << endl;
    
    if (IncludeCommments == true)
    {
        cout << "What is the comment for choice A for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
        getline(cin, userInput);
        WriteOut << userInput << endl;
    }
    else
        WriteOut << "" << endl;
    
    cout << "What is choice B for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);
    WriteOut << "B) " + userInput << endl;
    
    if (IncludeCommments == true)
    {
        cout << "What is the comment for choice B for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
        getline(cin, userInput);
        WriteOut << userInput << endl;
    }
    else
        WriteOut << "" << endl;
    
    cout << "What is choice C for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);
    WriteOut << "C) " + userInput << endl;
    
    if (IncludeCommments == true)
    {
        cout << "What is the comment for choice C for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
        getline(cin, userInput);
        WriteOut << userInput << endl;
    }
    else
        WriteOut << "" << endl;
    
    cout << "What is choice D for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);
    WriteOut << "D) " + userInput << endl;
    
    if (IncludeCommments == true)
    {
        cout << "What is the comment for choice D for question number " << i + 1 << "?\n";
        getline(cin, userInput);
        WriteOut << userInput << endl;
    }
    else
        WriteOut << "" << endl;
    
    cout << "Which choice is the right one? [A, B, C or D]\n";
    getline(cin, userInput);
    while (userInput != "a" && userInput != "A" && userInput != "b" && userInput != "B" &&
           userInput != "c" && userInput != "C" && userInput != "d" && userInput != "D")
    {
        cout << "Only A-D is accepted\n";
    }
    userInputChar = userInput[0];
    if (userInputChar > 96)
    {
        userInputChar -= 32;
    }
    userInput = userInputChar;
    cout << "userinput contains " << userInput << endl;
    cout << "userinputchar contains " <<userInputChar << endl;
    WriteOut << userInput << endl;
}
WriteOut.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the maximum number allowed?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to change the && in the below code to || to run the code the code correctly

```
if (userInput == "y" && userInput == "Y")
    IncludeCommments = true;
else
    cout << "Comments disabled by user...\n";
```

and coming to the validation you can maintain a flag variable after taking userinput

```
cout << "How many questions should the quiz have?\n";
getline(cin, userInput);
int length=userInput.length(); //gives the length of string entered
int flag=0; //flag variable
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
   if((!(userinput[i]>='0'&&userinput[i]<=9))||isspace(s[i])) //i am 
   considering space is not a problem
   {
      flag=1;
   }
}
if(flag!=0)
{
  cout<<"error:Non digit is entered"<<endl
}else
{
  int numberofquestions = stoi(userinput);
  if(numberofquestions<=1){
     cout<<"error:number less than 2 is entered"<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but don't name a variable `flag`; give it a name that tells the reader what it does. Also, the standard library provides `isdigit`, which you can use instead of checking against `'0'` and `'9'`. More important, though: once you've seen a bad input character, you don't need to check the rest. So add a `break;` statement after setting the flag. Personally, I'd write that loop as a separate function; if an error is detected, `return false;` if the loop runs to completion, `return true;`.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestions as i am new to programming these valuable feed backs are very helpful for good programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options that it is difficult to make a good recommendation.

I will show you several solutions. The first part has always the same approach:

- We run a do loop
- First we instruct the user, what to do
- Then we read the input
- Then we, check, if all are digits
- If we have all digits, then we convert to a number
- and check, if the number is greater than 1

If we find an error, we loop again. Let`s look at the options in the code below

1. Index based for loop and compare with character digits
2. Index based for loop and use of isdigit function
3. Range based for loop and use of isdigit function
4. all_of algorithm and use of isdigit function
5. regex. Will also handle empty lines
6. Extened regex. Will also handle empty lines AND will check if number > 1

Options 1-4 need an additional check for an empty line. User presses just enter.

Please see code with all options:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    // We try to get input from the user and run a loop as long as it is not OK
    bool inputIsOK{};
    // This is the number of questions that we want to read
    int numberOfQuestions{};

    // Ask for valid input from user
    do {
        // Assume valid input
        inputIsOK = true;

        // Instruct user
        std::cout << "\nHow many questions should the quiz have? Enter a number > 1.\n";

        // Read complete line from the user
        std::string line{};
        if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
            // Check, if all characters are valid (digits)
            // Option 1 -------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Index based for loop and compare with character digits
            for (size_t i{}; i < line.length(); ++i) {
                if (line[i] < '0' || line[i] > '9') {
                    inputIsOK = false;
                    std::cerr << "\nError 1: Please enter digits only\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Option 2 -------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Index based for loop and use of isdigit function
            for (size_t i{}; i < line.length(); ++i) {
                if (not std::isdigit(line[i])) {
                    inputIsOK = false;
                    std::cerr << "\nError 2: Please enter digits only\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Option 3 -------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Range based for loop and use of isdigit function
            for (const char c : line) {
                if (not std::isdigit(c)) {
                    inputIsOK = false;
                    std::cerr << "\nError 3: Please enter digits only\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Option 4 -------------------------------------------------------------------
            // all_of algorithm and use of isdigit function
            if (not std::all_of(line.begin(), line.end(), isdigit)) {
                inputIsOK = false;
                std::cerr << "\nError 4: Please enter digits only\n";
            }

            // Option 1-4 -----------------------------------------------------------------
            // For option 1 to 4 you need to additionally check for empty line
            if (inputIsOK && line.length() == 0) {
                inputIsOK = false;
                std::cerr << "\nError 5: Please enter digits only\n";
            }

            // Option 5 -------------------------------------------------------------------
            // regex. Will also handle empty lines
            if (not std::regex_match(line, std::regex("\\d{1,6}"))) {
                inputIsOK = false;
                std::cerr << "\nError 6: Please enter digits only (max 6)\n";
            }
            // Option 6 -------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Extened regex. Will also handle empty lines AND will check if number > 1
            if (not std::regex_match(line, std::regex(R"([2-9]|([1-9][0-9]{1,6}))"))) {
                inputIsOK = false;
                std::cerr << "\nError 7: Please enter number > 1  (Max 6 digits)\n";
            }
            // End Option -----------------------------------------------------------------

            // Check, if number is > 1
            if (inputIsOK) {
                numberOfQuestions = std::stoi(line);
                if (numberOfQuestions < 2) {
                    inputIsOK = false;
                    std::cerr << "\nError 8: Number too small. Enter number > 1\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "\nError: General problem with input\n";
            inputIsOK = false;
            std::cin.clear();
        }

    } while (not inputIsOK);
    return 0;
}
```

You can choose whatever option you want.

---

However. I would not use one of the above.

I would use the IOstream facilities and directly read an unsigned integer. If the input is wrong, the state of std::cin will goto fail and indicate the problem.

So, you could use that instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
int main() {
    // We try to get input from the user and run a loop as long as it is not OK
    bool inputIsOK{};
    // This is the number of questions that we want to read
    unsigned int numberOfQuestions{};

    // Ask for valid input from user
    do {
        // Instruct user
        std::cout << "\nHow many questions should the quiz have? Enter a number > 1.\n";

        // Get input. Directly as number
        inputIsOK = (std::cin >> numberOfQuestions) && (numberOfQuestions > 1);

        // In case of error. Show message
        if (not inputIsOK) {
            std::cerr << "\nError 1: Wrong input\n";
            std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    } while (not inputIsOK);
    return 0;
}
```

The `ignore` function will delete all the trash taht maybe still in the input buffer.